# Array of structs only takes last value in C

Tags: arrays, c, shell, struct

I'm trying to make a simple command line interface, but i'm having a probleme for parsing commands :

process_t is a structure contient the path of the command with arguments to be stored in the variable argv.

```
int parse_cmd(char* tokens[], process_t* commands) {
    assert(tokens!=NULL);
    assert(commands!=NULL);
    
    int position = 0;
    int commandNumber = 0;
        
    for(int i=0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++){
        if(is_reserved(tokens[i]) == 0 && tokens[i+1] != NULL) continue;
        int end = is_reserved(tokens[i]) == 0 ? i+1 : i;
        int argc = position;
        int count = 0;
        
        process_t newProcess;

        char* argv[MAX_CMD_SIZE] = {NULL};
        for(argc; argc < end; argc++) {
            argv[count] = tokens[argc];
            count = count + 1;
        }
        newProcess.path = tokens[position];
        newProcess.argv = argv;
        position = i + 1;
        commands[commandNumber] = newProcess;
        commandNumber = commandNumber + 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char path[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char* cmdline[MAX_CMD_SIZE];
    process_t cmds[MAX_CMD_SIZE];

    getcwd(path, MAX_LINE_SIZE);
    while (1) {
  
        printf("mini@shell:%s$ ", path);
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", line);
        
        trim(line);
        clean(line);
        tokenize(line, cmdline);
        
        parse_cmd(cmdline, cmds);
        toString(cmds);
        
        break;.
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

Input: ls -l ; grep ^a

---

Why the array contain only the value of argv of the last iteration ?

---

Output :

path : ls => argv = {grep, ^a, (null)}
path : grep => argv = {grep, ^a, (null)}

---

Comment: My guess: you need to make copies of the tokens, e.g. with `strdup`. See [mcve].

Comment: Yeah, the title almost screams 'copying a pointer instead of the char array pointed at'.  Probably 'newProcess.path = tokens[position];' :(

Comment: @MartinJames the path is stored in 'newProcess' as you can see in the output, but the argv array just like it takes the last argv array in for loop and give it to all the other process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the block-local array `argv`, which is recreated for every command and, what's worse, doesn't even exist any longer after `parse_cmd` has returned. An array object with sufficient lifetime has to be used; you can do this by changing

```
        char* argv[MAX_CMD_SIZE] = {NULL};
```

to

```
        char **argv = calloc(end-position+1, sizeof *argv);
```

Note that you'd have to `free` this object when no longer needed.

Also note that you forgot to `return commandNumber;` from `parse_cmd`; without that, you have no way of knowing how many commands were found.

Comment: Yeahh it worked ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I found also a way without even need to copy the local array that i declared, just by changing the value of the index that contain the reserved character.

So the tokens will be like this : `{« ls », « -l », NULL, « grep », « ^a », NULL}`

```
int parse_cmd(char* tokens[], process_t* commands) {
    assert(tokens!=NULL);
    assert(commands!=NULL);
    
    int position = 0;
    int commandNumber = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; tokens[i] != NULL; i++){
        if(is_reserved(tokens[i]) == 0 && tokens[i+1] != NULL) continue;
        int end = is_reserved(tokens[i]) == 0 ? i+1 : i;
        
        commands[commandNumber].path = tokens[position];
        commands[commandNumber].argv = &tokens[position];
        commands[commandNumber].next = &commands[commandNumber]+1;
        tokens[end] = NULL;
        commandNumber = commandNumber + 1;
        position = i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```